# Rsync to commit the transfer/mv after everything is locally saved

Tags: rsync

Is there a way to rsync a folder to a remove server folder but move everything only after the whole transfer is done?

I don't want files moved one after the other, because this would cause troubles with the running webserver.

I'd rather have the complete folder moved after everything is transfered on the server (which takes something like ~1s)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the **--delay-updates** option.
From `man rsync`:

> ```
>    --delay-updates
>           This  option puts the temporary file from each updated file into
>           a holding directory until the end of the transfer, at which time
>           all  the files are renamed into place in rapid succession.  This
>           attempts to make the updating of the files a little more atomic.
>           [...]
>           See  also the "atomic-rsync" perl script in the "support" subdir
>           for an update algorithm  that  is  even  more  atomic  (it  uses
>           --link-dest and a parallel hierarchy of files).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to have rsync place the files in an alternate directory outside the web-server's docroot. Then change the servers config to point docroot to the new folder and signal the webserver to perform a ["graceful"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html#gracefulrestart) reload of its config. With Apache this should guarantee that no requests are mishandled or dropped.

> The USR1 or graceful signal causes the parent process to advise the children to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately if they're not serving anything). The parent re-reads its configuration files and re-opens its log files. As each child dies off the parent replaces it with a child from the new generation of the configuration, which begins serving new requests immediately.

In other words, I'd automate this using a shell script and ssh rather than trying to find rsync options for managing your webserver.